# Python: Module Not Found

Tags: python

I have a program **'a.py'** which start with:

```
import XXX
```

The import works perfectly and **a.py** runs fine.

Then I wrote a program **'b.py'** which calls **'a.py'** to run continuously.
It looks like this:

```
import os
def main():
    return os.system("a.py") 
c=main()
while(c):
    c=main()
```

The I got the error says that `'Import error: no module named XXX'`

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

Both **a.py** and **b.py** are in the same folder.

Comment: Is the PYTHONPATH set properly so that the a.py can find the module ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation to make your code readable.  Edit your question.  Read the instructions on the right side of the page.

Comment: Make sure your Python is configured to allow XXX-rated content.

Comment: Okay, then.  Addressing the original question, the mostly likely culprit would seem to be PYTHONPATH.  Are you configuring your user shell (like, with .bashrc or .profile) to adjust the path?  That would account for differing search paths between running manually from the command line and with `os.system`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure zerocrates nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `os.system`, why don't you do an

```
import a
```

in b.py, and then call the function you want to run from a.py directly?

Comment: I want to run a.py from the begging to the end, basically, if a.py terminates, I would like to restart it. 

That's why I am having b.py to control this process

Answer (score 0):

Use OOP concept, make a class, put your code inside a function and call this function from constructor. and in b.py just call make an object of the class. and you are done.